# How can I include an HTML input in rails strong params?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create instances of a model "Post" with strong params that look like this:

```
  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, {images: []})
    end
```

In my form, this is how I upload files to `post_params["images"]`, and therefore to `post.images`:

```
<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

But I want to apply custom styling to the upload button, so I build one using HTML. But I can't figure out what `name` attribute to give the input so that it's included in `post_params`. Here's what I've tried:

```
<input name="images" type="file" multiple="true"/>
<input name="post[images]" type="file" multiple="true"/>
<input name="post['images']" type="file" multiple="true"/>
<input name=":images" type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

But they all just go to `params["post"]["images"]`, not `strong_params`.

**What name can I give an HTML input so it's included in strong params?**

Comment: If you use the `erb` version, then in the browser right-click -> inspect element. You should see what name it is generating. You can then use that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<input multiple="multiple" name="post[images][]" id="posts_images" type="file">
```

This should generate the correct JSON params that your controller is expecting. It can get confusing with the multiple levels of hash/array. That's why I use the `inspect element` in the browser as mentioned in my comment above to see what Rails is generating, then I can build custom styled elements to suit my needs.

One way to remember it is: You are `require`-ing `post`, and then looking for a hash with a key of `images` and a value of type `array`. That way it's easier to know where to use singular vs plural, what is the key, etc. So mapping it out syntactically would be:

```
<model name>[<key defined in strong params>][]
```

in the `.erb` version if you look at the top of your form, think about what the value of `f` is in the `... do |f|`. That's where it gets the controller name of `post` (singular) and then you are giving it the method name `:images` (plural) in the `file_field`. According to the Rails Docs you could use the singular `:image` but the plural seems more correct to me.

Comment: Also if you want to show the custom styling you are looking for, I might be able to show you how you can make that happen using the `file_field` method.